# Performing multiple deletion in REST API

Tags: rest, api

I have the `pages` and `history` table and I am using `redis` as the database.

I want to delete a history. However, for this, I want the `page_id` too. Now, in `REST`, how do you perform the deletion where two different `ids` are required?

Currently, I am thinking to do the following:

`https://www.example.com/api/:history_id/delete?page=:page_id`

I also thought to perform the action in `POST` request but will the `DELETE` operation be valid under `POST` request? I mean we generally `create` in `POST` request.

Comment: Why exactly do you want your page_id as well? Are you trying to delete both a page and a history, or is the history part of a specific page or the other way around and do you just want to delete the nested resource? How are your page and history related?

Comment: I have a redis stream which looks like `pages:<page_id>:histories`. This contains all the histories of a certain page. Now, to delete a record from the stream, I need the history id so that I can do `XDEL pages:<page_id>:histories history_id`. So that's the case.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have an identifier for the resource you want to delete, you are not in standard REST. REST is made for CRUD operation on a specific resource. The operation you want to perform, it is more like a business action.
So, you can send it in POST and specify the business operation as query string parameters, header, or body...or you can adopt another standard like [JSON-RPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification).

So, you can force REST for business operation or you can adopt another standard.